# 複数のテキストファイルであるパターンを変換

Tags: テキストファイル, sed, csv

複数のテキストファイルがあります：

例：

```
0dd6b4f419f3489a580846fb4ebe831b|one: [$numVotes$ more votes needed]
0dd6b4f419f3489a580846fb4ebe831b|other: [$numVotes$ more votes needed]
89e050644a71fbf8170e280f59fb8940: An error occurred during submission
a4c510816f6c806507bb528c240ed9a9: [closed]
2de9c2314772731359c387be3656bc19: Are you sure you want to award your bounty to this answer? THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE!
```

最初はキーで、複数系が単独系に差がある場合、キーの後に「|one:」か「|other:」がでてきます。単独系・複数系に差がない場合、その部分が抜けていますので、キーの直後に「:」しかないです。

エクセルへインポートしたいため、CSVファイルにしたいです。

```
|one: → ,one,
|other: → ,other,
: → ,,
```

「:」の後にも「:」がでてくる可能性があるため、最初の「:」だけに適用したいです。

*NIXの「`sed`」を利用できるはずですが、どのように使えばできますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foo.txtからfoo.csvへ変換するのであれば、
このように使ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
cat foo.txt | sed -e "s/|\(one\|other\):\|:/,\1,/" > foo.csv
```